# JQuery onclick parameter passing with append

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, asynchronous

Im currently trying to append a variable amount of text to a list. Each item would need to be clickable with their own value being passed to a function. I cannot seem to get this to work and keep getting a **'Object' is not defined at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick** error, where object is the name of the object in the list. Here is the code that I am using for this:

```
if (user) {
  id = user.uid;
  ref = firestore.collection("Users").doc(id);
  console.log(user);
  console.log(ref.get());

  ref.get().then(function(doc){
    nameString = doc.data().name;
    console.log(nameString);
    const outputHeader = document.querySelector("#headMain");
    const outputInfo = document.querySelector("#genInfo");
    outputHeader.innerText = "Welcome " + nameString;
    outputInfo.innerText = "Create a class or choose a class from the left";
  });

  firestore.collection("Users").doc(id).collection("Classrooms").get().then(function(querySnapshot){
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc){
      classNameString = doc.id;
      console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
      $("li").append('<a href = # onclick = "testInfo('+doc.id+')">'+doc.id+'</a><br/>');
    });
  });
}
```

The current testInfo function is as follows:

`function testInfo(val){
  console.log(val);
}`

Comment: Please post your full code.

Comment: Just posted more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following html code cannot work

```
<a href = # onclick = "testInfo('+doc.id+')">'+doc.id+'</a>
```

You are missing the double quotes, so the onclick is executed on the anchor element (the "#")

What you want to do is:

```
<a href="#" onclick="testInfo(\''+doc.id+'\')">'+doc.id+'</a>
```

Comment: Sorry, I also forgot the escaped quotes. Does it work now?

Comment: I am now getting an _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token val_ error with my testInfo function. Any idea why?

Comment: So I retyped my line of code and for some reason, that fixed it. Thank you very much for your help!